# How to get google maps API to stay in one point

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a Google maps working on my website, however I want it to focus only in NYC. I do not want the map functionality to work outside NYC location. How should I go about this? I have accessed the users location and then directed them to the map, however, should I remove that feature, and just have the map focus on certain coords? Please and thank you for any help.

```
var map;
var service;

function initialise(location) {
    console.log("location:" + location);
    var currentLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude);
    var mapOption = {
        center : currentLocation,
        zoom : 14,
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOption);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position : currentLocation,
        map : map,
    });
    marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png');


    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', performSearch);

    function handleSearchResults(results, status) {
        console.log(results)
    }

    function callback(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                createMarker(results[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    function createMarker(place) {
        var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map : map,
            position : place.geometry.location
        });

        ....

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            var latitude = this.position.lat();
            var longitude = this.position.lng();
            console.log(this.position);
        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
        var input = $("#search").val();
        var query = (input != '' )? input : "starbucks";
        performSearch(query);
    });
    function performSearch(q){
        var request ={
            bounds: map.getBounds(),
            query:String(q)
        };
        service.textSearch(request, callback);
    }
}

function initializer() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        zoom: 13,
    });

    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        browserSupportFlag = true;
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
            map.setCenter(initialLocation);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position : initialLocation,
                map : map,
            });
            marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png');
        }, function() {
            handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
        });
    }
     }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializer);

$(".getSearch").click(function () {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialise);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

Create a bounding box to restrict the extent of the map to just NYC area.

There are various way to achieve that:

for simple use, you can just bind a handler to change the map bounds (`panToBounds`) back to the default one when the event `bounds_changed` occurs.